# How to execute multiple server side methods on ajax call in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that is call by jquery and its result show on a popUp. Sometime it takes time to complete and blank popup appears with processing.When click on close popup disappears but method keeps running on server side.I want to stop execution by another method via ajax call,I know server side does't except request until complete earlier request.
What should i do?? i can't use asynchronous call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("StopMyMethod")',
  type: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  data: { boolValue:true },
  success: function (data) { 
    alert('success'); 
  },
  error: function (data) {  
    alert('Error'); 
  }
});
```

and server side code is

```
Boolean StopOvsPersonalDataDetail = false;
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyMethod(int id){
  foreach(var a from list)
  {
    if (StopOvsPersonalDataDetail)
      break;
    }
  return View(list);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult  StopMyMethod(Boolean boolValue){
  StopOvsPersonalDataDetail=true;
  return view;           
  }
```

Comment: First lesson of the web (more specifically http) : It is stateless, which means that boolean flag (StopOvsPersonalDataDetail) is wrongly used

Comment: You cannot abort a thread in the middle of a `foreach` loop like that! It never yields control to the other method to ever set that variable.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Could you please guide me with code.thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.may be it can help......

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url:'@Url.Action("StopMyMethod")',
            data: { boolValue:true }, //Pass as required
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            error: function ('data') {
            alert('Error') },
            success: function (data) 
            {
            if (data == true) {
              //required code here
            }
            else{
               //show error
                 alert('alert');
                }
            }
        });
```

and

```
 [httpGet]
 public  ActionResult MyMethod(int id)
 {
  try
   {  
    foreach(var a from list)
    {
      if (StopOvsPersonalDataDetail)
       break;
    }
        return View(list);
  }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    return false;
}
```